# Scope of Function access in C

Tags: c, function, scope

Suppose I have a function that I want to use internally such as `private` in Java or C++, but I am writing in C. In this case, I have a header file and a `c` file implementation and the `c` file has several functions that should not be available to the end user. Is it ok for me to not declare these functions in the header file in order to prevent access to them or is this bad practice / is there a better way?

Comment: That's precisely what static functions are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty much what you would do in this case and add static to the declared functions. You would declare your public functions in the .h file and the private functions in the .c file.

Let's say you had a .h and .c file as such:

#### SomeFile.h

```
void doSomething1(void);
void doSomething2(void);
```

#### SomeFile.c

```
static void doSomething3(void);
static void doSomething4(void);
//These functions can be called by anyone
void doSomething1(void)
{
    //function guts here
}
void doSomething2(void)
{
    //function guts here
}
//These functions can only be called inside this file
static void doSomething3(void)
{
    //function guts here
}
static void doSomething4(void)
{
    //function guts here
}
```

Comment: A function (or any name in general) only need to be declared seperately from its definition if it is used before the latter. Normal practise is to define them before usage. This avoids redundancy (this cannot be avoided for names with external linkage).

Answer (score 0):

Make such internal function `static` and keep it just in `.c` file.

See [static functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Procedures_and_functions#Static_functions):

> If a function is to be called only from within the file in which it is declared, it is appropriate to declare it as a static function. When a function is declared static, the compiler will now compile to an object file in a way that prevents the function from being called from code in other files.

Or in the C standard:

> **6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**
> ...
>   If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.<sup>1</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1</sup> A function declaration can contain the storage-class specifier static only if it is at file scope ....

Answer (score 0):

Yes its ok to make some of the functions not available in the header file.

The other options are to separate the header files into 2. One for internal use and other for external user.

Apart from that also you can declare the functions static making them not visible outside the file scope

Answer (score 0):

Declare these functions directly in the `.c` file as static functions and provide the definitions of the functions in the same file:

Ìn the .c file:

```
static void internal_func1(void);
static int interal_func2(int a);

static void internal_func1(void)
{
   /* body of internal_func1 */
}

static int interal_func2(int a)
{
   /* body of internal_func2 */
}
```

Adding the `static` keyword makes these functions invisible to other source files (the function identifier will have *internal linkage*).